# Free SQL Server Management Studio memory usage

Tags: ssms-2012

Is there a memory usage limitation for SQL Server Management Studio and is there a way to free SSMS memory without rebooting it? I am currently using SSMS 2012 and I always getting error message like below:

```
'An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'
```

My computer has 24GB RAM and the free memory is 17GB but I still get above message when executing some heavy queries. I store some xml data in tables so the query can bring huge data back. However this issue is not occurring all the time. usually it is after I run SSMS for a while that makes me think it is a memory usage limition. at this moment I have to reboot SSMS to get my query executed. Is there a way to free memory without rebooting SSMS?

Comment: Is your copy of SSMS a 32-bit app? If so, it won't use more than 2 or 3 GB of RAM no matter how much you have available.

Comment: It is 64 bit. I just checked version. Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5266.00 (X64) 
 Mar 17 2011 15:18:02 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Comment: Isn't that the **server** version?

Comment: Is there a way to check SSMS version? As I am using 64 bit OS, I think the SSMS should also be 64 bit but I just can't remember it.

Comment: You can look at "Ssms.exe" in Task Manager (32-bit apps have a "*32" suffix) or figure out from file location (mine is at "C:\Program Files (x86)\").

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a 32 bit version. So if I install a 64 bit version that can handle more memory and potentially execute heavier query?

Comment: I can't tell you whether 64-bit will fix anything (or even if there's a 64-bit version available). But a 32-bit application can by no means use your 17GB of free RAM.

Comment: This makes sense. I will try installing a newer 64 bit version and see if this can be improved. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Álvaro González is right. I installed a 64 bit SSMS and haven't seen same issue again so far.